# Setup function says object is not defined, even tough it is defined in the function and is being returned

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

It says that the newBlog is not defined but I am returning it from the setup function and using it in the event handler function I don't understand what the issue might be?

```html
<template>
  <form @submit="onSubmit" class="add-form">
     ...
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity'
    export default {
        setup() {
            const title = ref('')
            const body = ref('')
            
            const onSubmit = (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()

                const newBlog = {
                    title: title,
                    body: body
                }

                this.$emit('add-blog', newBlog)

                title.value = ''
                title.body = ''
            }
            return { title, body, onSubmit, newBlog }

        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`newBlog` is declared inside the `onSubmit` function, and it's not accessible outside of that scope, leading to the error you observed.

To fix the issue, move the `newBlog` declaration outside `onSubmit`:

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    //...

    const newBlog = {...}

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
      this.$emit('add-blog', newBlog)
    }

    return { title, body, onSubmit, newBlog }
  }
}
```